# Delay issues while using iZotope RX3 for noise reduction and restoration

Tags: noise-reduction, delay

I just recently purchased iZotope's RX3 suite and beginning to incorporate it into my workflow. When I use it as a plugin within Pro Tools, some plugins from the suite cause a delay. Activating Pro Tools' Delay Compensation feature fixes the problem, but then negatively affects other tracks that don't require a delay compensation. Is it possible to assign a delay compensation for specific tracks only? I guess I could shift regions in my timeline according to the delay compensation but it just doesn't feel like the efficient way to go.

Anyone else familiar with managing delays while using the RX3 suite (or other plugins) ?
Should I just avoid using RX3 as a plugin and do all necessary processing via the standalone app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome!
i think it's best to check out the protools forums on this subject. 
and if you want a proper answer there (or here), you should also specify your software version, pc/mac, processor, and settings more clearly. 
with regards to protools and 'delay compensation' it's a frankenstein implementation that is only fixed in 11HD (i think). You cannot 'assign' compensation to 1 track or more tracks, only to all.

Cheers,
Arnoud